# Using Zend_PDF in a stand alone mode, how to set the include of the land class

Tags: php, zend-framework, autoload, require-once

I'm writing a tiny school project in php. I needed to display some information in a pdf format and send the file via mail.

When i've copy the PDF folder with the pdf class file from the librairy.here is my folder structure

> ```
>   /
>     /lib
>       /Swift
>         /....
>       /Zend
>         /Pdf
>         Pdf.php
>     test_file.php
> ```

here is the content of test_file.php

```
require_once 'lib/Zend/Pdf.php';
$pdf = new Zend_Pdf();
$pdf->render();
```

and it's throwing this

> ( ! ) Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Zend/Pdf/Page.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR;C:\ZendFramework-1.10.8\bin;') in C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolproject\lib\Zend\Pdf.php on line 27

but i did notice that all classes includes by referring to the top Zend folder, even siblings classes ex :

```
require_once 'Zend/Pdf/Page.php';
```

i'm a little confuse about how to deal with that. I'm think about autoload feature or manually correct the require path to suit my project (which will be a pain).

What's the best way to go around it?

THanks for reading this.

Comment: Add the library folder of your project to the include path: `include_path=".:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/path/to/zf"` - via [Zend Framework: "Location, Location Location!"](http://devzone.zend.com/article/4683)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register the ZF autoloader. After that you can just use the classes and the autoloader will figure out the rest.

```
$zf_path = 'PATH/TO/YOUR/LIB/FOLDER';
set_include_path($zf_path.PATH_SEPARATOR.get_include_path());
require_once($zf_path.'/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php');
$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$loader->registerNamespace('Zend_');
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the fast response. I think i get the idea.That means i would need to add `Zend Loade`r folder and `Loader.php` to the `Zend` folder of my `lib`.
most important question is where will the code you posted reside? in a `boostrap` kind of file which i include in my php files? thanks again

Comment: I have a hard time understanding your comment. Where exactly your Zend-Code is, does not really matter, as long as you add it to include path. You have to load the Zend_Loader_Autoloader before you use any of the Zend classes. It can be anywhere in your code though: "At the top", in a bootstrap file oder in some lazy autoloading construct - it depends on the system / framework you are using. If you use symfony1 for example, that code would go into the project configuration class.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you need to configure your include path to the root of the Zend Framework library folder.

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    'c:\ZendFramework-1.10.8\library',
    get_include_path(),
)));
```

As Zend uses pseudo namespaces, you need to include the toplevel directory `library/` and not `library/Zend`

You may also want to use [Autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
```

It avoids you to call `require_once()` each time you need to 'require' a file to load a Class

Comment: Since the project will be deployed on the school server, i rather avoid to tie it to my environment, i prefere including the needed library itself in the lib folder thanks

Comment: Whatever you use the complete bundled library or standalone files, you NEED to use the toplevel folder because of the require_once statement used in ZF. However set up your include path accordingly to your environement and it'll work.

Comment: where should this code `require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();` itself be put ? thanks

Comment: It really depends on your application, however, it should be set before any use of the Zend Framework components. If you have a front index.php, it may be the place to put it. You may also want to put it just before to call new Zend_Pdf();